# How to create a media entity via rest api

Tags: media

Getting a 422 Unprocessable Entity while trying to create a media entity via rest api. I've failed to find any docs regarding what params/entity type I need. This is how I usually create entities via core rest.

```
const data = {
  _links: {
    type: {
      href: serverUrl + '/rest/type/entity/media/image',
    },
  },
  field_media_image: [
    {
      target_id: response.data.fid[0].value, // uploaded file ID
    },
  ],
};

return postNode('/entity/media', data, props.token);
```

I've tried `rest/type/entity/media` as well. Both `media` and `media/image` return the same error.

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnprocessableEntityHttpException: Type {domain}/rest/type/entity/media/image does not correspond to an entity on this site. in Drupal\rest\RequestHandler->deserialize() (line 184 of /var/www/{domain}/core/modules/rest/src/RequestHandler.php).

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure `postNode()` is using a POST request?

Comment: @apaderno yes. I use the same function throughout my webapp.